# How to attach data from API request inside v-model

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to attach data from Axios request inside Vue component to v-model but it doesn't want to load for some reason...

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div>
        <div class="form-group mb-4">
            <label for="section_english_name">Section English Name</label>
            <input v-model="form.section_name_en"  ref="section-name-english" type="text" name="title"  class="form-control" id="section_english_name" >
            <div v-if="form.errors.has('section_name_en')" v-html="form.errors.get('section_name_en')" class="text-danger"/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

inside Data()

```js
data() {
    return {
        addonSection: {},
        addonDetails: [0],
        form: new Form({
            section_name_en: this.addonSection[0].name_en,
            section_name_ar: '',
            quantity: 0,
            addon_select_type: 1,
            hide_addon_item: 1,
            addon_name_en: [],
            addon_name_ar: [],
            price: [],
        })
    }
},
```

Methods:

```js
loadAddonSection () {
    axios.get('/vendor/addons/' + this.addonid + '/edit').then((data) => {
        this.addonSection = data.data;
    })
},
```

[image: Console error here]

Vue data() doesn't even load in Vue tool bar I don't know why!!

[image]

When i comment "this.addonSection[0].name_en" it loads data perfectly
[changed it to string or when i remove it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6omk.png)

Comment: How can it read `this.addonSection[0].name_en` when the component is created when `this.addonSection` has no data ????

Comment: when i add this line "this.addonSection[0].name_en" it gives me the error but without it loads data perfectly with no issues

Comment: Yeah, because that is the issue... Read my comment again...

Comment: then how am I supposed to load data inside my v-model... I want to attach my data from my API request to my form ....please check my post again

Comment: You have to read the documentation again... See [Vue Lifecycle](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)... [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-component-lifecycle) is the most important one... When `created` lifecycle has run, `data` is available... so you are trying to run `this.addonSection[0].name_en` when `this.addonSection` is empty... so it will never read the API... The `section_name_en` should be `section_name_en: ''` and when `created` hook begins, you should there read the API and store the data you want...

Answer (score 1):

Read your errors.

```js
        addonSection: {},  
addonDetails: [0],
  form: new Form({
     section_name_en: this.addonSection[0].name_en,
```

You say section_name_en is this.addonSection[0].name_en , which 2 lines above you initialize as an empty object, does that makes sense?

Initialize your section_name_en as something empty and then you update what you like inside you Axios success call!

Before entering the Axios function set var `self = this` so because inside the axios function `this` refers to the axios, so if you want to modify a Vue variable you can now use `self.addonDetails.section_name_en = AxiosResult`

Hope it helps, good look buddy.

Comment: That is not correct, as `this` inside an arrow function is the general scope not the function itself, so doing `this.addonSection = data.data;` in that case is correct.

Comment: You are correct, to be honest I didn't read his Axios function/